# How to use *ngIf to test if a variable is defined Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Is there a way to use *ngIf to test if a variable is defined, not just if it's truthy?

In the example below, the HTML displays a shipping cost for the red item only, because item.shipping is both defined and nonzero. I'd like to also display a cost for the blue item (shipping defined but zero), but not for the green item (shipping not defined).

> JavaScript:

```
items = [
      {
        color: 'red',
        shipping: 2,
      },
      {
        color: 'blue',
        shipping: 0,
      },
      {
        color: 'green',
      }
    ];
});
```

> HTML:

```
<ul *ngFor='let item of items'>
    <li *ngIf='item.color'>The color is {{item.color}}</li>
    <li *ngIf='item.shipping'>The shipping cost is {{item.shipping}}</li>
</ul>
```

it didn't work.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'shipping' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'shipping' of
>   undefined

Comment: I would like to display 3 items on the page, but it displays errors in Ionic 3.

Comment: I tried typeof(item.shipping)!==undefined, but it's not working.
please help me !
Thank you

Comment: I've never used Angular.js (yet), but quickly looking at the docs, it appears one can use quite complex conditions. I'm very tired, so am not posting an answer, but check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#-lt-ng-container-gt-to-the-rescue for hints.

Comment: according to the error message, it says you are retrieving `shipping` from `undefined`, I think it's not relevant with *ngFor. check other parts for using `item.shipping` or `xxx.shipping`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could using something like this

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items">
    <li *ngIf="item && item.color">The color is {{item.color}}</li>
    ....
</ul>
```

or using `safe navigation operator`

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items">
    <li *ngIf="item?.color">The color is {{item.color}}</li>
    ....
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tiep Phan

`<li *ngIf='item?.shipping'>The shipping cost is {{item.shipping}}</li>`

It is working for me !